# python django 1.9 ImportError: No module named djano.conf.urls

Tags: python, django

Im following the tutorial on the Django website https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/intro/tutorial01/

im down to the mysite/urls.py section, i have added the code

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^networks/', include('networks.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

However when I run the server I get:

```
ImportError: No module named djano.conf.urls
```

Ive searched through here and everything points to an old version of Django, but im running the latest version i believe

```
python -c "import django; print(django.get_version())"
1.9.5
```

Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: `ImportError: No module named djano.conf.urls` where is `g` in django?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a Typo error:

```
ImportError: No module named **djano**.conf.urls
```

That's why you're getting this ImportError.

Comment: blooming heck, thanks for that! wood for the trees i think!